# How to make producer threads to wait for consumer threads to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

Each operation will create main thread in our application and this thread will create tasks and submitted by **ExecutorService**.

Currently these producer threads will add tasks to `ArrayList`, from which threads from `threadPool` will execute tasks.

During High load (when there are many operations), I am getting **"Jvm out of memory"** errors.

**How i can avoid this situation by making main threads to wait for some time based on some limit?**

Comment: Why don't you just limit the amount of threads?

Comment: Hint: you want to run a java profiler / enable GC logging in order to **really** understand what happens to your memory consumption. You can't fix a problem that you don't understand.

Comment: Re, "Each operation will create main thread..."  When most developers say "main thread", they are talking about the first thread in the JVM to execute your application's code.  In that usage, there can be only one "main thread", and it can not be created _by_ your application because it was created _for_ your application.

Answer (score 3):

Out of memory is another issue, but you want [producer/consumer with blocking queue](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html).

If consuming threads in your executor pool can't process requests fast enough the blocking queue will fill up.  Once it's full, producers will be blocked from adding new tasks until consumers can process requests and free up room.

This may not solve your OOM issue.  You need to profile the code to see where memory is being consumed.  Perhaps your consumer threads aren't cleaning up when they're finished or there is static data that's not reclaimed by the GC.

It might be that this is a situation like the [Sorcerer's Apprentice](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cornel1801.com%2Fdisney%2FFantasia-1940%2Ffilm3_3.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cornel1801.com%2Fdisney%2FFantasia-1940%2Ffilm3.html&docid=Bi9j0M2FBMatvM&tbnid=ulM8sGAI7lYJvM%3A&w=464&h=336&bih=875&biw=1164&ved=0ahUKEwjb4vjz6JXNAhXC7B4KHX4oDw8QMwgqKA0wDQ&iact=mrc&uact=8).  You'l get an OOM error if the producers are creating requests so quickly without stopping that the `ArrayList` expands without end until all your memory is consumed.  If that's the root cause, then blocking deque will fix it.

Comment: No. Deque is required so producers add from one end and consumers take from the other. Blocks producers when it's full.

Comment: Euhm, that's what a queue does, the article you linked, doesn't even talk about deques...
A deque just allows removing and adding on both ends. That is functionality you don't need for the Producer Consumer pattern.

Comment: I see this when I click on the link: "Using Blocking Queue to implement Producer Consumer Pattern".   No, a queue is different.  You can do what you like.  The example I've cited used blocking deque.  Please feel free to post your own.

Comment: I see this line in the code example at that link:    BlockingQueue sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();  What were you reading?

Comment: I've read exactly that, it uses a blocking queue, not a blocking deque.

Comment: Whatever - do you have anything constructive to offer?  Please post your answer.

Comment: The constructive bit is that I think you can improve your answer, which is already good. Duplicating yours, with the correction is less productive I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ExecutorService to execute the tasks, then I will suggest you that instead of default implementation of thread pools, you can define your own thread pool with custom configuration by instantiating the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the required configuration. See below:

```
/**
     * Creates a new {@code ThreadPoolExecutor} with the given initial
     * parameters and default thread factory and rejected execution handler.
     * It may be more convenient to use one of the {@link Executors} factory
     * methods instead of this general purpose constructor.
     *
     * @param corePoolSize the number of threads to keep in the pool, even
     *        if they are idle, unless {@code allowCoreThreadTimeOut} is set
     * @param maximumPoolSize the maximum number of threads to allow in the
     *        pool
     * @param keepAliveTime when the number of threads is greater than
     *        the core, this is the maximum time that excess idle threads
     *        will wait for new tasks before terminating.
     * @param unit the time unit for the {@code keepAliveTime} argument
     * @param workQueue the queue to use for holding tasks before they are
     *        executed.  This queue will hold only the {@code Runnable}
     *        tasks submitted by the {@code execute} method.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if one of the following holds:<br>
     *         {@code corePoolSize < 0}<br>
     *         {@code keepAliveTime < 0}<br>
     *         {@code maximumPoolSize <= 0}<br>
     *         {@code maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize}
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code workQueue} is null
     */
    public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                              int maximumPoolSize,
                              long keepAliveTime,
                              TimeUnit unit,
                              BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    }
```

Here , you can provide your own BlockingQueue with the size defined by you, so now in this case when the queue is full then further new tasks will wait until the queue has space to accept new tasks.

With this implementation, you can control and tune the thread-pool as per your requirements.

You can click this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more detailed information, You may find it boring :P, but trust me you will find it very useful, once you read it so just read it patiently.. :)